# Using a CASE in an Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a load of rules about how a result set must be ordered. I need to use a CASE to work out the columns to order by.

I am trying this:

```
ORDER BY
              CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date) IS NOT NULL AND icbm.emma_id IS NOT NULL -- We have it all!
                          THEN ISNULL(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date) DESC , icbm.emma_id , version_number , icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id]
                    WHEN ISNULL(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date) IS NOT NULL AND icbm.emma_id IS NULL -- We have an appearance date, but it's manual.
                          THEN ISNULL(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date) DESC, icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id] DESC
                    WHEN ISNULL(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date) IS NULL AND icbm.emma_id IS NOT NULL -- No appearance date, but it has a Business Message
                          THEN icbm.emma_id DESC, version_number DESC, icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id] DESC
                    ELSE icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id] DESC -- No Appearance date, not Message.
               END
```

But it seems I can only include one column after the THEN. But I need tio use a few columns, based on my rules.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can use this ugly code in select cluase of subquery without ordering and then order by one column in parent query

Comment: @Andrey: But each THEN wants to return multiple things to order by. I think you'd need four CASEs with the same conditions (one for each component that you want sort on); or, if SQL Server supports arrays and sorts them sensibly then you could return arrays from each branch of the CASE (I think PostgreSQL would support this sort of chicanery, don't know about SQL Server).

Comment: @mu is too short: No arrays in T-SQL.

Comment: You could also repeat the logic once for each column substituting a constant value under the conditions where you have no column to sort by in that case, but I would imagine that would be even uglier than a subquery.

Comment: The core problem with the idea in the OP is, of course, that you can't tell SQL to sort an entire result over different columns based on the values in one row.

Comment: I believe a `DESC` is missing at the end of the very first `THEN` list.

Comment: Note Standard SQL only allows column names and `AS` clauses ("aliases") or their ordinal positions in the `ORDER BY` clause. I think the idea is this prevents the sort order from being made opaque to the caller, which strikes preventing bad practice. Put another way, consider relocating your `CASE` expression to the `SELECT` clause and give it a meaningful `AS` clause name so it is transparent to the the caller how the resultset was sorted.

Comment: mootinator - That is indeed the problem I overlooked. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To order a result set by diferent rules on different rows does not really make sense, as the conflicting rules will create inconsistencies in how individual orderings between rows are made.  In other words there is no consistent ordering if the ordering rules are inconsistent.

However I suspect you are making this issue much more complicated than it needs to be.  I suspect you can just order by:

```
ISNULL(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date) DESC , icbm.emma_id , version_number , icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id]
```

The NULL values will sort themselves out and be sorted together.  Perhaps start from here and figure out what needs to change.

Comment: +1 but the last item should probably have the `DESC` specifier (the OP must have missed it in the first THEN, because `DESC` appears beside `icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id]` in three other places.

Comment: This looks good - but actual_appearance_date and sheduled_appearance_date can both be null. Would this still work?

Comment: Well it will still work in the sense that those rows will be sorted on the NULL values. The real questions is whether that ordering is useful to you, or whether you need to tweak the above to meet your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, `CASE` is an expression that returns a single value, not a control of flow statement (like in some languages). Therefore you will need to repeat expressions where multiple columns might be needed to order... and each expression needs to return compatible data types. There are probably some shortcuts possible in here, and I may have missed some of the logic, but if you create aliases for some of these columns and then use a subquery, it can help make all the CASE structuring easier.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT
        /* other columns */
        as_date = COALESCE(actual_appearance_date, scheduled_appearance_date),
        emma_id = icbm.emma_id,
        vn = version_number, 
        ca = icaci_t.[ijis_court_appearance_court_item_tracker_id]
    /* rest of query */
) AS x
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN as_date IS NOT NULL THEN as_date END DESC,
CASE WHEN as_date IS NOT NULL AND emma_id IS NOT NULL THEN emma_id END,
CASE WHEN as_date IS NOT NULL AND emma_id IS NULL THEN ca END DESC,
CASE WHEN as_date IS NULL AND emma_id IS NOT NULL THEN emma_id DESC,
CASE WHEN as_date IS NOT NULL AND emma_id IS NOT NULL THEN vn END,
CASE WHEN as_date IS NULL AND emma_id IS NOT NULL THEN vn END DESC,
CASE WHEN as_date IS NULL AND emma_id IS NOT NULL THEN ca END DESC,
ca DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is one way you can do it but it is an UGLY UGLY hack.

Simply concatenate your columns (convert them if they are not varchars) and add them left to right.

THEN SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), actual_appearance_date,111)) + convert(VARCHAR, emma_id)

You will need to make sure your date string is formatted YYYY, MM, DD (such as above) so that the order is correct. If you want the order by for a column descending, you can reverse the string.

This solution will work but is morally appalling so use it at your peril.